# How to access the POST fields of a form built with the form builder?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I am trying to write a registration form with Symfony 4 I had added a password confirmation field.

```
class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ...
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
            ->add('password2', PasswordType::class, [
                'label' => 'Password Confirmation',
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ...
```

And the controller I use the "password" field and the "password2" field to compare them if they are identical

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="app_user_registration")
 * @return Response
 */
public function userRegistration( Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder ) : Response
    {
        $user =  new User();
        $userRegistrationForm = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);

        $userRegistrationForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userRegistrationForm->isSubmitted() && $userRegistrationForm->isValid() ){
            $submittedList = $request->request->get('user_form');
            if($submittedList['password']  === $submittedList['password2'])
            {
```

As you can see I had to use :

```
$request->request->get('user_form')['password'];
```

instead of

```
$request->request->get('password');
```

as the documentation suggested :  [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object)

Can someone help me to understand where my mistake is to not be able to use the method according to the doc

Answer (score 0):

`$data = $userRegistrationForm->getData();` will return an array only if the form is not associated with an `Object` otherwise it returns an Object.

Therefore `$data` and `$user` will give both a User Object with the same data which can be accessed with getters, so it doesn't help.

However `password2` is unmapped because it is not associated to the User Object but the `Form` Object has a method to get any field even unmapped which is : `$form->get('password2')->getData();` and this will return the submitted value.

Additional info [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/forms.html#unmapped-fields) and [here](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/symfony-basics/video/how-to-get-the-request-query-parameters-in-symfony)